# How do I get a Min and Max from certain ids in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, max, min

I got a database with certain colums I am working with the adress and the time(unixtime) but I need to calculate from all colums with the same record(value) from the colum adres the time between the first and the last one

So lets say adress x has 3 entries, then I want to sort the time from min to max. So I need to sort on adress, then time from min to max/max to min so I can calculate how long the person stayed there (time)

[image: This is my Query atm]

Comment: Please, add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

I thin, you want `group by` and the difference in times:

```
select address, min(from_unixtime(time)), max(from_uixtime(time)),
       ( max(from_unixtime(time)) - min(from_uixtime(time)) ) as diff
from sensordata1
group by address;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant thank you for this! Is there also a option to calculate the time they stayed for each adress? You got diff but how do I get that in unix time?

Comment: @thattom . . . This does calculate the diff at each address.

Comment: I mean I need this time in minutes

Comment: @thattom . . . Divide by 60.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT address
        , MAX(FROM_Unixtime(time))  as myMaxTime
        , MIN(FROM_Unixtime(time)) as myMinTime
        , TIMEDIFF(MAX(FROM_Unixtime(time)), MIN(FROM_Unixtime(time)))
    FROM sensordata1
    GROUP BY  address
```

If you do not want to return the entire dataset

Comment: This is exactly what I meant thank you for this! Is there also a option to calculate the time they stayed for each adress?